# Intellij 13 SonarQube plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube

I have installed the SonarQube plugin in Intellij Enterprise 13. When I follow the configuration instructions at:  https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin, no inspection errors or warnings are found, even though the code explicitly violates rules that have been returned by the Sonar server to the Intellij plugin and which are visible in the 'inspections' profile.

I have a multi-module SpringMVC project thats being built with Gradle. I am not sure if this is relevant.

Does anyone have the SonarQube plugin working in an Intellij 13 Java project? Could you share any details of your configuration process or tweaks you needed to make that are not covered in the plugin documentation at the link above?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your information, SonarSource is currently working on a brand new plugin for IntelliJ: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-intellij

Comment: Trouble is, you don't seem to be able to install it in IntelliJ 13.1.1; I get the error "Fail to load plugin descriptor..." when trying to install from a zip file (i.e. from disk).

Comment: @Christian You do not need it install it from a zip file as it is available on the plugins list ("Browse repositories") by default.